# Laravel validation for option list: if value is not in DB then give error

Tags: laravel

I have an option list in my front end and the data is retrieved from the DB table, named `countries` and `nicename` column.

[image]

Trying to prevent the user request for value which is not in `countries` table and in `nicename` column. I have created custom validation, which works fine but it looks like it's not too professional way of doing this control. I have seen somewhere that there is shorter way of doing this validation by `in:table_name,column_name`. But it did not work for me Maybe I am doing something wrong?

```
$rules = [
 'shop_country' => [
                            'required',
                            function ($attribute, $value, $fail ) {
                            $found_country = '';
                                $countries = Country::get()->toArray();
                                foreach ($countries as $country) {
                                  if ($country['nicename'] === $value) {
                                      $found_country= $country['nicename'];
                                  }
                                }
                                if($found_country === ''){
                                    $fail('The country is not valid!');
                                }
                            }],
]
```

Comment: You don't need to write this logic yourself, Laravel has an [`exists`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exists) validation rule for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it as:

```
'shop_country' => ['required|exists:table_name,column']
```

[See docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exists)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by using the `exists` validation rule.
You can check it in the [official laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exists).

Also this is an example they provide

```
'state' => 'exists:states'
```

Comment: states is not the column name but the table name

Comment: you are correct, i edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`exists`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exists) validation rule:

> The field under validation must exist in a given database table.

```
$rules = [
  'shop_country' => ['required', 'exists:countries,nicename']
];
```

> In the above example, the table name is assumed to be `countries`.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate nicename as string

```
 'shop_country' => 'required|string|exists:countries,nicename',
```

Or validate country id itself

```
 'country_id' => 'required|integer|exists:countries,id',
```